# How to give map network drive path in console application?

Tags: c#, sql, console-application

I made one console application which take backup of Sql database, and store it to given path,
It works perfect when i give this path as local Drive, But when i give path to map network drive path, means i want to save my backup in other network pc, it show error

> Cannot open backup device
>   'Z:\Smart_Tracker_03_01_2014_12_44_21_F_1_0.bak'. Operating system
>   error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.). BACKUP DATABASE
>   is terminating abnormally.

Below is my code:

```
Success_backup = Execute_Query_Master_Database("BACKUP DATABASE " + DatabaseName + " TO DISK = '" + Backup_FileName + "' ");
Success_Alter_DB = Execute_Query_Master_Database("ALTER DATABASE " + DatabaseName + "  SET MULTI_USER ");




public static  bool Execute_Query_Master_Database(string strQuery)
    {
        SqlConnection Conn = null;
        SqlCommand _command;

        {

            string connectionstring = @"Data Source=" + servername + ";Initial Catalog='master';User Id='" + UserName + "';Password='" + PassWord + "'";
            Conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

            Conn.Open();
            _command = new SqlCommand();
            _command.Connection = Conn;
            _command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            _command.CommandText = strQuery;
            _command.CommandTimeout = 0;



            _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return true;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Error occured in Function - Execute_Scaler_Master_Database()");
            Console.WriteLine("Error Message as below : ");
            Console.WriteLine("===========================");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine();

            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            _command = null;
            Conn.Close();

        }
    }
```

Kindly noted I pass 6 arguments

```
      string[] args = new string[6];
        args[0] = "VARUN-PC"; //Sql Name
        args[1] = "Smart_Tracker"; //DataBase name
        args[2] = "sa"; // user Name
        args[3] = "admin@12"; // Password
        args[4] = "F"; // Backup type "F"mean full Backup here
        args[5] = @"Z:";  // path where to store database, here map drive
```

Comment: Does the user account your process uses, have enough user rights?

Comment: Does the mapped drive definitely exist? (can you browse to z:\ in command prompt?)

Comment: My user Account has administrator (Full Rights), and i can browse that Z: drive from command prompt

Comment: The account that SQL Server is running under doesn't have a drive `Z` mapped - the drives that *your* account has mapped don't matter. Is there a reason for wanting to use a mapped drive rather than a UNC path?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I also try to Give UNC path but it also shows same Error Operating System Error 5.

Comment: No, that's a different error. Error 3 in your original question was that it couldn't find the path specified. Error 5 (in your most recent comment) is access denied - the user account that SQL Server is running under doesn't have *permission* to write to the location you're specifying.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ya u right, its access Denied. so, what should I do here?
sql store in my PC n it have Administrator rites,
And i try different PC in networks but same error Showing.